# Retraction of a Pushout is a Pushout

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a diagram with the outer square being a Pushout. Each asterisk is a different object, and morphisms $R,I$ are different morphisms that satisfy $RI=id$.I wish to show that the inner square also satisfies the universal property of pushout.

[image]

Note that the diagram may not necessarily be commutative. For example, I think that $IiR=j$ doesn't hold in general. Given two morphisms to some object, we can get a unique arrow from the outer right bottom object using the universal property:
[image]

We have that $F_1R=\Phi j$, and the same for bottom arrows some of which I left unnamed. I'm tempted to say that $\Phi Ii=F_1$, if if $\Phi I$ was unique, it would prove that the inner square satisfies the universal property. Since I've mentioned that the diagram may not be commutative, I cannot really conclude $\Phi Ii=F_1$. If it was though, I would claim that $j=IiR$ and from $F_1R=\Phi j=\Phi IiR$ I would get that $F_1=\Phi Ii$ by cancelling $R$ on right. However, I don't think I can do it. Even if I managed to show existence, I also have troubles with showing uniqueness. I think I could let there be another morphism $\Phi^{\prime}$ so that $F_1 = \Phi^{\prime} i$ and somehow show that it must be equal to $\Phi I$. We get an arrow $\Phi^{\prime} R$. Then we have $\Phi^{\prime} R I i R = F_1 R$. If we assume the initial diagram commutes, the latter equality simplifies to $\Phi^{\prime} R j = F_1 R$, which further implies $\Phi^{\prime} R = \Phi$  by the universal property of the outer square. Finally, after composing with $I$ on the right, we imply that $\Phi^{\prime} = \Phi I$.

I think I worked through it correctly, but commutativity is what confused me.

[image]

What am I missing?

**Motivation.** I may be missing some details in my question, so I will include the context. This lemma should be used to prove a corollary to Seifert-van Kampen theorem for subgroupoids.

> Corollary. Let $X$ be a topological space covered by open sets $U,V$ with $A$ being its subset. Let $\Pi_A(X)$ be a full (fundamental) subgroupoid with objects being elements of $A$. If $A$ intersects every path component of $U,V, U\cap V$, then the diagram below is a pushout.[image]

Note that we get the usual statement of Seifert-van Kampen for fundamental groupoids if we remove the $A$-subscript. $i, j$ above are just inclusions. The proof goes by constructing left-inverse functors $R$ for each of inclusion functor $I: \Pi_A(U) \to \Pi(U)$ and then using the statement from my question, i.e. by using the diagram without the A-subscript as an outer square and the diagram above as the inner square. $R$ are constructed separately for $U \cap V$, $U \setminus V$, and $V \setminus U$ by choosing for each element $x$ of respective set a path to some element $R(x)$ in $A$; object $x$ is mapped to $R(x)$, and path $\gamma: x\to y$ mapped to some path $R(x) \to R(y)$ obtained by composing with chosen paths $x \to R(x)$ and $y \to R(y)$. For elements in $A$ we choose a constant path. This way we have $R$ is a retraction functor and that $R$'s (and I's) define a morphism of squares.

Comment: Does retract of the pushout square mean that both the $R$-morphims **and** the $I$-morphisms form a morphism of squares?

Comment: Are you sure that it is true?

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, they should be if I understand correctly. I included the context below. I'm afraid I could be missing some details, but hopefully including the motivation should clear misunderstandings.

Comment: @KritikerderElche I may have made mistakes in posing this question because I may not understand some details myself. I've edited my post by including the concrete motivation, so hopefully it should be more clear now.

Comment: if I and R are retracts of the whole diagram, then the diagram needs to be commutitave, and I think that is something necessary you need, and in your case also holds. In that case you should be able to push the unique morphism to the inside. Been some time though since I did stuff like that.

Comment: @Enkidu why does commutativity hold in my case? We have $j \ne IiR$, because $j$ sends an object $x$ to $x$, while $IiR$ sends $x$ to $R(x)$. If it was the case, though, I think I could prove the statement.

Comment: Have you tried to construct a counterexample? I'd try maybe the category of vector spaces because there every subobject is a retract.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category with colimits of shape $\mathsf{I}$. A cone under a functor $F:\mathsf{I}\to\mathsf{C}$ can be regarded as a functor $\overline{F}:\mathsf{I}^\triangleright\to\mathsf{C}$ extending $F$, where $\mathsf{I}^\triangleright$ is the category obtained from $\mathsf{I}$ by adjoining a terminal object, which we denote by $\infty$. It suffices to show that if $\overline{F},\overline{G}: \mathsf{I}^\triangleright\to\mathsf{C}$ are functors, $\overline{F}$ is a colimit cone, and $\overline{G}$ is a retract of $\overline{F}$ (in the functor category $[\mathsf{I}^\triangleright,\mathsf{C}]$), then $\overline{G}$ is also a colimit cone. Let $\overline{G'}$ be the colimit cone of $\overline{G}\vert_{\mathsf{I}}$. The universal property of colimits gives us a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\overline{F} @>\operatorname{id}>>\overline{F}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\overline{G} @>>> \overline{G'}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\overline{F} @>\operatorname{id}>>\overline{F},
\end{CD}$$

and we wish to show that the middle horizontal arrow is an isomorphism. This follows from the fact that a retract of an isomorphism is again an isomorphism. (You can prove the last claim for $\mathsf{Set}$ and appeal to the  Yoneda lemma.)